# Automatic checks for strict weak ordering

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

The [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) function relies on some form of a pairwise comparison subroutine. This subroutine may take the form of an explicitly provided comparison function,  or may take the form of an `operator<` overload. In either case, the comparator must define a strict weak ordering. If the comparator does not define such an ordering then this results in undefined behavior. An example is provided in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978201/why-does-stdsort-throw-a-segmentation-fault-on-this-code). I have, in my own experience, come across scenarios where comparing two objects' data with `<=` instead of `<` results in a range of non-deterministic errors including stack or heap corruption and segmentation faults.

So my question is: **Do any tools exist for identifying invalid comparators that do not enforce a strict weak ordering?**

I had originally hoped to find a GCC flag (e.g. "-Werror=require-strict-weak-ordering"), but I haven't been able to find something like this. Considering how easy these errors are to introduce, how difficult they can be to diagnose, and how widespread the possible effects are, I am surprised that some form of automatic detection isn't the default in GCC. Even if this can't be detected at compile time, a runtime assertion would be quite useful. Anything would be better than a corrupt stack and hours of guessing.

Comment: The simplest way is to always use the tuple comparison like: `return std::tie(lhs.a, lhs.b)  < std::tie(rhs.a, rhs.b);`. As in general, it is not possible to check strict weak ordering.

Comment: There are library implementations that do checks for this at runtime in debug mode. However, they only check the arguments that are passed to them, they don't do an exhaustive check. That would be impossible unless you were dealing with a type which has a very small domain. Sometimes it's not even desirable when you plan to restrict your domain. For example, `<` is not even a valid comparator for floating point types, because of NAN. But that certainly isn't going to stop people from sorting doubles and floats that way.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Library implementations check only subset of strict ordering axioms, to avoid increasing complexity of underlying algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Both LLVM and GCC STL implementations do some basic runtime checking if you enable *debug mode* (via `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` for libstdc++ and `-D_LIBCPP_ENABLE_DEBUG_MODE` for libc++). But they only do basic checking and in particular do not test comparator's transitiveness.

There are tools that perform complete checking of passed data:

- for C: https://github.com/yugr/sortcheck
- for C++: https://github.com/yugr/sortcheckxx

They verify all strict ordering axioms but check only subset of input data (to avoid increasing complexity of the underlying algorithm to `O(N^3)`).